# Not able to see other images in Product view of Configurable Product in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, color-swatches

I'm creating a **configurable** product in Magento 2, and I added 3 images (let's say **A,B,C**) in the configurable product section **Images and Videos**.

Then I create configuration based on **color** and select 2 colors (**black and blue**). I also add 2 images for each color (let's say **BC1, BC2** for black and **BL1, BL2** for blue).

After saving when I view it in front end, on selecting black color swatch I see **BC1, A, B, C** images and on selecting blue color swatch I see **BL1, A, B, C**.

What I wanted to see is on selecting black, **BC1 & BC2** images should display and on selecting blue, **BL1 & BL2** images should display.

Is there any configuration that needs to be done?

Comment: There isnt't configuration for that. Only one child product image is used to swatch.